# Finite dimensionality of fibers of etale ring map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

While working through a proof of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.04148.pdf) paper, at the middle of page 46, the author introduces a dimension notion which seems to claim that the following is true:

> Let $A\rightarrow B$ be an [etale map of rings](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00U0). Then
>   $$
> \sup_{P\in \text{Spec(A)}}\{\dim_{\kappa(P)}\kappa(P)\otimes_{A}B\}
> $$
>   exists and is finite, where $P\subset A$ runs throughout the prime ideals of $A$ and $\kappa(P)$ is the residue field at the prime ideal $P$.

Why is that true? Throughout the resources that I looked through, I can only see why the $\dim_{\kappa(P)}\kappa(P)\otimes_{A}B$ is finite, but why is there a uniform bound?

Comment: Etale maps are flat, hence fibers have the same degree over connected components. There are only finitely many components so that gives a uniform bound?

Comment: @Asvin: This argument works for *finite* étale maps only. In general, we may use Zariski's main theorem: there is a finite $A$-algebra $\overline{B}$ and an $A$-morphism $\overline{B}\to B$ inducing an open immersion of the spectra. Clearly, $\dim_{\kappa(P)}\kappa(P)\otimes_AB\leq\dim_{\kappa(P)}\kappa(P)\otimes_A\overline{B}$ which is bounded by the number of $A$-module generators of $\overline{B}$.